# Django - prepopulated_fields slug textfield

Tags: django

Following is my models and admin class. However, slug is not pre-populated? Why? my title is a `Textfield`.

```
class Deals(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=1000, db_index=True, unique=True)


class DealsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
    list_per_page = 20

admin.site.register(Deals, DealsAdmin)
```

As per [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields), prepopulated_fields doesn’t accept DateTimeField, ForeignKey, OneToOneField, and ManyToManyField fields. So, it should accept TextField.

Why the slug is not prepoulated?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, the field is prepopulated in this case. JS is well activated in the browser ? Or do you try with the same Deal object ? "Prepopulated fields aren’t modified by JavaScript after a value has been saved"

Comment: No, I'm creating a new object.

Comment: Prepopulated works on normal CharField, but not on TextField.

Comment: Found the bug!! In my chrome console., I get the below error.

`prepopulate_init.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).prepopulate is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (prepopulate_init.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at prepopulate_init.js:4
    at prepopulate_init.js:10`

Comment: i'm using version 2.2, maybe it has been fixed

Comment: Yeah!! Maybe. I'm on 1.11